# Can Only Print When Local Admin

Tags: windows-7, network-printer

We have a user on our domain that just of over a week ago that printing stopped working to our network printers. All other people can print to these printers without issue and if someone else logs onto their computer they can print too.

Now the kicker, we placed in the user in the Local Administrator group on the computer and they can now print. Took them out, can no longer print. We tried removing printers and adding them back, still can't print. We have also checked the security settings on the printers installed on the computer, no issues.

So we are stuck, any other troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Is there a domain controller present and are there policies in effect? If so, test if disabling the policies for the user makes it work. (don't forget the `gpupdate /force` and a reboot)

Comment: There is a domain controller and group policies, but they are the same for everyone in the organization. No domain or group policy changes have been made recently. Will look at trying this and see if we can do this.

Comment: I've seen a corruption in the local group policy database causing weird things, and they were restoring if the group policy was changed and synced. My test basically does that.